# Dividable properties of factorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the maximum value of $n$ that $300!$ is divided by $6^n$.

I used

$$
n_{max}=\Big[\frac{300}{6}\Big]+\Big[\frac{300}{6^2}\Big]+\Big[\frac{300}{6^3}\Big]=59
$$

But there is no $59$ among multiple answers. Is this because $6$, not a prime number? How is it solved if a divider is not a prime number?

Comment: [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) is for primes.  What is the highest power of $3$ in $300!$?  Does that power of $2$ divide $300!$?

Comment: There are $100$ numbers from $1$ to $300$ devisable to $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$6=2\times 3$, and we only need to focus on the numnber $3$(think about the reason).
$$
\left[\dfrac{300}{3}\right]+\left[\dfrac{300}{3^2}\right]+\left[\dfrac{300}{3^3}\right]+\left[\dfrac{300}{3^4}\right]+\left[\dfrac{300}{3^5}\right]
$$